# bitwise function to compare any possible option combination

Tags: bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators

I am having the following enumeration:

```
typedef enum _options {          
    o1=1,
    o2=2,
    o3=4,
    o4=8
} option;
```

Is it possible to have one function to check any combination of them, like (logically speaking):

`o1 OR o2 OR o3`

`o1 AND o2`

`o1 AND (o2 OR o3)`

`(o1 OR o2) AND (o3 OR o4)`

The following work for `option=(o1|o2|o3)` but not for `option=((o1|o2) & (o3|o4))`

```
BOOL doesMyValueHaveOption(option o) { 
    int v = myValue;
    return (v & o);
}
```

Comment: what are you trying to accomplish? your question is unclear. Also, oX values in your enum seems odd (there is no need to shift number by 0. X<<0 == X)

Comment: That enum should probably be `o1 = 1, o2 = 2, o3 = 4` etc

Comment: I edited the question. I need to have a single function to evaluate combinations of options.

Comment: `o1 = 0` means it is either always present or never, depending on your interpretation.

Comment: you are right, I removed 0 and updated the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, but not like that. Observe the values of `option` that you get to see why - as soon as you AND together two sub-queries, everything goes wrong.

For arbitrary queries, you will need *at least* a list of options (each of which is also a combination), either in Sum Of Products or Product Of Sums form. That means you'd have to convert a query (which is really an expression tree) into one of those forms, which may result in exponential blowup. It may still be a reasonable approach though, depending on the structure of your typical query. If it really has to be general, you'd better just pass it as a tree (or maybe a DAG, you may as well share equal sub-trees).

If you go for the Product Of Sums form, your queries would look like `(o1 OR o2 OR o4) AND (o2 OR o3 OR o5) AND (etc..`, you'd pass a list `{o1 | o2 | o4, o2 | o3 | o5, etc }` and implement it as (not tested)

```
BOOL doesMyValueHaveAllOptions(vector<option> options) { 
    int v = myValue;
    for (auto o : options)
        if (!(v & o))
            return false;
    return true;
}
```

For Sum Of Products form, your queries would look like `(o1 AND o3 AND o4) OR (o2 AND o4 AND o5) OR etc..`, you'd pass a list `{o1 | o3 | o4, o2 | o4 | o5, etc}` note that while the o's are connected by "AND" in the query, they're combined with OR in the list (because otherwise it's just zero), and you could implement it as (not tested)

```
// todo: make up a better name
BOOL doesMyValueHaveAtLeastOneCombinationOfOptions(vector<option> options) { 
    int v = myValue;
    for (auto o : options)
        if ((v & o) != o)
            return false;
    return true;
}
```